# Unity UxmlAttributeDescription not setting values (resetting values)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ui-toolkit

I'm using the UI Builder for my UI and I'm creating some custom controls. I've already managed to make a custom control which works perfectly fine. But the second one has some problems I can't understand.

The problem:
I'm able to put my custom control into the UI Builder. From the start there is no default value in the "status" attribute, it just blank. When I manually input a value and click away, the "status" value is reset to blank.
In the console I'm getting the message "null" from the constructor, meaning the value I input was not set.

Additional information:
The problem first occurred when I used the class UxmlIntAttributeDescription. I had a class with an UxmlStringAttributeDescription and an UxmlIntAttributeDescription. I was able to set the string attribute, but not the int attribute. I kept simplifying my code so I can post this question and then even the string attribute broke.
I really don't know where I screwed up, hopefully someone can help me with this one.

Here is my code. Its mostly copied from https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-UXML.html.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class TestElement : VisualElement {
    public new class UxmlFactory : UxmlFactory<TestElement, UxmlTraits> { }

    public new class UxmlTraits : VisualElement.UxmlTraits {

        UxmlStringAttributeDescription m_status = new UxmlStringAttributeDescription { name = "status", defaultValue = "TestElementString" };
      
        public override IEnumerable<UxmlChildElementDescription> uxmlChildElementsDescription {
            get { yield break; }
        }
        
        public override void Init(VisualElement ve, IUxmlAttributes bag, CreationContext cc) {
            base.Init(ve, bag, cc);
            var ate = ve as TestElement;

            ate._status = m_status.GetValueFromBag(bag, cc);
        }
    }

    private string _status;
    
    public TestElement() {
        Debug.Log(_status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `AttributeDescription`'s name should end with `Attr` suffix
- corresponding public `{get;set;}` property must exist & named the same but without that `Attr` suffix

Serialization system won't work with this element otherwise.

```
public class TestElement : VisualElement
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public new class UxmlFactory : UxmlFactory<TestElement,UxmlTraits> {}
    public new class UxmlTraits : VisualElement.UxmlTraits
    {
        UxmlStringAttributeDescription statusAttr = new UxmlStringAttributeDescription { name = "status", defaultValue = "TestElementString" };
        public override void Init(VisualElement ve, IUxmlAttributes bag, CreationContext cc)
        {
            base.Init(ve, bag, cc);
            var ate = ve as TestElement;

            ate.status = statusAttr.GetValueFromBag(bag, cc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, what I needed to do, was to change `private string _status;` to `private string status { get; set; }` . It seems that its also important for the variable to not start with `_`. 
But the `Attr` suffix was not needed. Maybe that got changed.

Comment: That's plausible. I only know about this because someone mentioned that on the forums last year. It's surprising that this documentation page never even mentions that serialization system expects anything.

Answer (score 0):

This could have changed throughout the updates. Just reporting in that I am using Unity 2022.3.10f1 and in my tests the only important thing is that the variable name of the VisualElement must match with the `name` property of the `UxmlAttributeDescription`

So this should work out fine:

```
enter code here

public class TestElement : VisualElement
{
    public string myCustomValue { get; set; }

    public new class UxmlFactory : UxmlFactory<TestElement,UxmlTraits> {}
    public new class UxmlTraits : VisualElement.UxmlTraits
    {
        UxmlStringAttributeDescription thisNameDoesNotMatter = 
            new UxmlStringAttributeDescription 
            { 
                name = "my-custom-value",
                defaultValue = "TestElementString"
            };
        public override void Init(VisualElement ve, IUxmlAttributes bag, CreationContext cc)
        {
            base.Init(ve, bag, cc);
            var ate = ve as TestElement;

            ate.myCustomValue = thisNameDoesNotMatter.GetValueFromBag(bag, cc);
        }
    }
}
```